# Record Selection Formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report, formula

I have a basic report with three available search parameters. The three parameters are Date Range, Layers, and Customer. When the report is launched the user is faced with the "Enter Values" screen with these three search parameters. At the moment, the report cannot be executed unless all three search parameters are selected. I would like the user to be able to choose between only wanting layers or customer in their search parameter. For example, user selects their date range, and selects a number of layers. The report would then bring back all customers that has that specified number of layers. And vice versa with the user selecting only the customer name and the report bringing back all customers with all layers. My current record selection formula is attached.

```
{@ModCriteria} = 0 and
{QuoteHistory.ModDate} = {?Date Range} and 
{UDFQuotePart.Layers} = {?Layers} and
{CustAddress.Name} = {?Customer}
```

Comment: When you create a parameters then you need to compulsory provide the data when you run the report..on thing you can do is you can manipulate the parameters like if you don;t want to give then just select `None` and provide data for other parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Value Option of each Parameter to Optional Prompt. Then in your record selection formula change each one with the parameter to match the following.

```
(if hasvalue({?Parameter}) then 
   {table.field} = {?Parameter} 
else 
   {table.field} like "*")
```

Then all they need to do is insert the Parameters that they want and leave the others blank.